# How to handle RoutedEvent in a grid with command in MVVM light wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM light to refacter my code. My old code looks like this-

```
<Grid x:Name="root" ButtonBase.Click="LayoutRoot_Click">
```

The LayoutRoot_Click will handle all the RoutedEvent from child controls.
Because the grid have no command interface ,so the new code like this

```
<Grid x:Name="root" ButtonBase.Click="LayoutRoot_Click">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ButtonBase.Click">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding InputCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=button1}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The viewmodel like this-

```
public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        InputCommand = new RelayCommand(InputCode);
    }

    public ICommand InputCommand { get; set; }

    private void InputCode()
    {
        string input = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. The command did not get the RoutedEvent.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding PassEventArgsToCommand="True" to your command binding

```
<Grid x:Name="root" ButtonBase.Click="LayoutRoot_Click">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ButtonBase.Click">
        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding InputCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=button1}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Your command would then have to have a parameter of the correct type which I think is RoutedEventArgs

```
public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> SomeCommand { get; private set; }
    private void SomeCode(RoutedEvent routedEvent)
    {
        //Do something with the routed event
    }
```